# Concatenating directive attribute to template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a possible way to use the value of an attribute and use it to concatenate in the directive template

```
<text-input txt-info="textName" ng-model="pi.medRecNumber"> </text-input>

hcare.directive('textInput', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE', //attribute or element
    scope: {
        bindedModel: "=ngModel", // Element Model Data
        txtInfo:'@', // Serve as name and id attribute value
    },
    template:
            '<div class="form-group tcell-220" data-ng-class="{true: \'has-error\'}[submitted && formHcare.'+txtInfo+'.$invalid]">'+
                '<div class="fg-line">' +
                    '<input id="'+txtInfo+'" name="'+txtInfo+'" data-ng-model="bindedModel" type="text" class="input-h25 form-control" placeholder="M#####-#"  >'+
                '</div>'+
                '<small class="help-block" data-ng-show="submitted && formHcare.'+txtInfo+'.$error.required">Field Required</small>'+
            '</div>',
    replace: true,
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function($scope, elem){
        // LOGIC HERE
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working..
The thing with directives is that you have the same scope as the parent so you don't really need the 'bindedModel' variable and you can approach the txtInfo attribute with {{}} as we always do in angular.

Here is your code with my fixes to make it working:

```
hcare.directive('textInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE', //attribute or element
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      //bindedModel: "=ngModel", // Element Model Data
      txtInfo:'@', // Serve as name and id attribute value
    },
    template:
    '<div class="form-group tcell-220" data-ng-class="{true: \'has-error\'}[submitted && formHcare.{{txtInfo}}.$invalid]">'+
    '<div class="fg-line">' +
    '<input id="{{txtInfo}}" name="{{txtInfo}}" data-ng-model="pi.medRecNumber" type="text" class="input-h25 form-control" placeholder="M#####-#"  >'+
    '</div>'+
    '<small class="help-block" data-ng-show="submitted && formHcare.{{txtInfo}}.$error.required">Field Required</small>'+
    '</div>',
    //require: '?ngModel',
    link: function($scope, elem){
      // LOGIC HERE
    }
    };
});
```

don't forget to initialize the pi object in the controller for it to work:

```
hcare.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.pi = {};
});
```

If you want to make sure it is working you should use the browser's inspect element option on this input field.